# NSDictionary Maximum size of data key

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What is the maximum size allowable in an NSDictionary data key? i.e.:

256 bytes, 1024 bytes, etc.

Comment: The keys in an `NSDictionary` are objects—items of type `id`. They are stored as pointers and don’t really have an inherent “size”. What kind of object are you trying to use as the key?

Comment: I would like to save binary data like a small graphic within a plist and store it as needed.

Comment: @user3549620 Based on your comment, why is your question about the key since it seems like you really want to know about the values?

Comment: @maddy, My concern is that I would want not want to store data in the NSDictionary that exceeded a size limitation or would cause issues with performance when reading it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no size limit *per se* on the keys or values in an `NSDictionary`, as others have pointed out only references to the key and value objects are stored, and a reference is usually 4 or 8 bytes. The size of your objects is primarily limited by the size of your (virtual) memory.

However, as indicated by your comments, this does not appear to be your actual question. Rather you are concerned over the size an on disk representation of a dictionary may be without causing performance issues. While reading very large files into memory takes time you can read many megabytes easily and a few "small graphics" in a dictionary is unlikely to be an issue.

Using a plist is not your best choice - these are serialised representations of quite a limited set of data types, `NSImage` for example is not one of them, and are more suited for other uses. You should look instead at the standard Cocoa archiving classes, these will handle any class which implements `NSCoding`, and many standard classes do including collections (`NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, etc.) and images. Read the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/archives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000946-BAJDBJAI).

HTH

Comment: Interesting, in particular what you've mentioned about NSImage. I've only read data from a file into NSImage before, so I assume there's no way for it to access a string of data as if it were reading it from a file. I will have to re-think some things likely based on that info I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Maximum size limits in bytes for NSDictionary Key.

Maybe if you meant to ask about the maximum limit of a NSDictionary value then there is no such limit.

NSDictionary's key's uniqueness is decided by `hash` method of NSObject.

**Update:**

If you want to get the benefit of fastness of dictionary access and along with that if you want to persist your data then a double layered approach might work for you. In this approach;

First, the data is stored into `NSMutableDictionary`, then in the background its pushed into the plist file. It looks something like this.

In .h file, declare

`NSMutableDictionary *userDictionary;`

Then in the .m file, define methods like this,

```
- (void)storeValue:(id)value forKey:(id)key {
    [userDictionary setValue:value forKey:key];
    [self commitIntoPlist];
}

-(id)getValueForKey:(NSString *)key{
    return [userDictionary objectForKey:key];
}

- (void)removeObjectForKey:(NSString *)key {
    [userDictionary removeObjectForKey:key];
    [self commitIntoPlist];
}

//commit the data into plist
- (void)commitIntoPlist {
    dispatch_once(&onceCommitToken, ^{
        commitQueue = dispatch_queue_create([@"com.yourappname.commit" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    });
    dispatch_async(commitQueue, ^{
        //here write the dictionary into plist
        [self writeDictionaryIntoPlistFile:userDictionary];
        });
}
```

Using this approach you get the speed of dictionary and the persistence of Plist together. You could keep this class as singleton, and dont forget to allocate the `NSMutableDictionary` before using.

Comment: The main concern is what I mentioned earlier, and the fact Apples Documentation says "it’s best to not use data objects in property lists to hold large amounts of binary data.". What do they define as "large"? 1MB, 100GB, 1TB?

Comment: NSDictionary is not equal to plist file. So keeping a large binary data into NSDictionary is not going to hurt performance. Im using similar method to store large data into plist on background thread. I will update my answer.

Comment: Nice example, I've used dispatch queues before, so it makes sense. Do you ever have to create a buffer in addition to the using dispatch queues for any of the items you read from the NSDictionary? just curious.

Comment: I did not have to. All I had to do was to lazily initialize the dictionary once the app is initialized. Dictionary access is almost equivalent to Constant access if a good hash method is used. Only one thing thats faster than dictionary access is Class Property(iVar) access. But inorder to do that you need to define your entities before hand. You could optimize the above sample further. But I hope you get the idea!

Answer (score 0):

The keys and values in an `NSDictionary` are objects—items of type `id`. They are stored internally as pointers, which have a fixed size. There is no object that is “too big” to put into an `NSDictionary`.

(If you want to serialize your dictionary to a plist, you’ll need to be sure that the dictionary only holds [the data types that can be serialized for you](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html).)

Comment: Is it better to serialize data, and what do you mean by fixed size?

Answer (score 0):

The things in an NSDictionary have to be objects. Since objects are always stored by reference rather by value, the size of the object doesn't matter at all.

If you need to store arbitrary data in a Foundation collection but don't think an object wrapper would be worthwhile, NSValue and NSData are generally your best bets.

Comment: That's good to know. My concern was that if I stored an object that was for example 100KB that it might cause memory issues when accessing it, etc.